# Reference a slide in Beamer

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

I have an example in my beamer presentation which I mention in another page. I want to include the page of that example in an automatic way. Here is my code. The reference to the example is on the last page.

Thank you.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}

\title{Main Title} 
\author{Jane Doe}
\institute{University A}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First Page}
\begin{exampleblock}{Example}
This is an example which will be used later.
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Second Page}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Third Page}
\begin{itemize}
\item In this slide, we are going to use the sample example on page 2. % Here I want to reference the page of the example automatically.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you want to reference it exactly? I assume page numbers won't have much meaning here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Place a label to the frame you want to cross-reference and then use `\ref`:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}

\title{Main Title} 
\author{Jane Doe}
\institute{University A}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First Page}
\begin{exampleblock}{Example}
This is an example which will be used later.
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label={important}]
\frametitle{Second Page}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Third Page}
\begin{itemize}
\item In this slide, we are going to use the sample example on slide~\ref{important}.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if I want to reference a slide but in an overlay of it?

Answer (score 4):

The classic command `\label{}` works too.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}

\title{Main Title} 
\author{Jane Doe}
\institute{University A}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First Page}
\begin{exampleblock}{Example}
This is an example which will be used later.
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Second Page}
\label{important}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Third Page}
\begin{itemize}
\item In this slide, we are going to use the sample example on slide~\ref{important}.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

An even nicer way is to write.

```
...
\item In this slide, we are going to use the sample example on \hyperlink{important}{\beamergotobutton{Second Page}}
...
```

"Second Page" would be typically be the title of the slide you referring to.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.